# igraph in R not showing edge arrows

Tags: r, igraph

I am creating a network graph in R using the igraph library. The input data is an adjacency matrix. However, there are no edge arrows connecting the vertices.

My weighted adjacency matrix looks something like this:

```
    A  B  C  
A   0  3  5  
B   2  0  6
C   0  7  0
```

This is my code in R:

```
net <- graph.adjacency(adj_matrix, mode = 'undirected', weighted = TRUE, 
diag = FALSE)
plot(net)
```

I am quite new to this. I thought that the vertices would be plotted according to my matrix and that the edge arrows will map the relationships (i.e. there should be an arrow connecting A to B since the (A,B)th index is non-zero).

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: You specified that the graph is undirected. Which way would the arrow point?    Just leave off `mode = 'undirected'`

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel dumb for asking this now.

Comment: We all miss things.  I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your adjacency matrix to the edge data format, using the following code:
network=graph_from_adjacency_matrix( adj_matrix, weighted=T, mode="undirected", diag=F)

please check this link for detail:
https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/250-correlation-network-with-igraph/